# Listings: Define new language from Emacs highlighting

Tags: listings, emacs

In my document, I need to include code written in `Macaulay2`, which is not a predefined language in `listings`.

To define it myself, I started looking for a list of keywords, and found the variable describing the syntax highlighting in Emacs. I have uploaded the file [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=63430454308698254026).

This contains a list of keywords, which is great, but it also includes regular expressions. I know nothing about regular expressions, so I am unsure of how to handle them. I can of course delete the regular expressions and simply add the keywords in the usual manner:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Macaulay2}
{
    morekeywords = {FirstKeyword, 
                    SecondKeyword}
}
```

But if the regular expressions give Emacs additional information about how the keywords should be treated, then I would like `listings` to have that information as well.

Comment: In case the listed link goes dead, [I've re-uploaded to GitHub.](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/e1eaa4f32fdb031dc0406d17ceb9cc39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [lstlang0.sty](http://folk.uio.no/martibhe/LaTeX/Macaulay2/lstlang0.sty) with the list of keywords from `M2-symbols.el`. When stored locally, `listings` will automatically import the file and then it is possible to highlight keywords using `language = Macaulay2`.

The keywords are divided into four groups, as explained in Sean's answer. By default, these typeset in the same manner. However, you can distinguish them in `\lsetset{}` like this:

```
keywordstyle = [1]\color{red},
keywordstyle = [2]\color{blue},
keywordstyle = [3]\color{green},
keywordstyle = [4]\color{yellow}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can verify that the regular expressions in `M2-symbols.el` do not give Emacs any additional information other than what the words mean.  There are four categories listed in `M2-mode-font-lock-keywords`:

- Types (`ComplexField`, ...)
- Function names (`associatedPrimes`, ...)
- Constants (`CallLimit`, ...)
- Generic keywords (`and`, `break`, `catch`, ...)

That's the only 'extra' information Emacs has (and that extra information has nothing to do with the regular expressions themselves).

In `listings`, I don't believe there is a way to provide this information built-in (in, e.g., a `morefunctions` key).  Refer to the documentation (particularly section 4) for other ways to set these keywords apart (like the `emph` and `moreemph` keys).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `listings`, you could try to use the package `minted`, that relies on the external program `pygmentize` (http://pygments.org/).  As the homepage states:

> support for new languages and formats are added easily; most languages use a simple regex-based lexing mechanism